# Stop HTML format in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

HTML formatting can't seem to fit our needs and is always crapping out our code. I wish I could turn it out but can't seem to find the way to do it.

I still want my PHP code to be formatted in HTML templates but I don't want PhpStorm to format my HTML anymore.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use a formatter to reformat your code... for example, PHP can be formatted to PSR-2 standards. You can configure that under settings > editor > Code Style > PHP or for html that is under the HTML branch. But when you have both in the same file it will always format PHP and HTML according to the rules. I can't seem to tell it to NOT format the HTML cause it's messing up everything!

Comment: Why would it be case closed @HendraNucleo?

Comment: There is no option to ignore certain language formatter unfortunately. I do not know what issues you have got there with HTML formatting right now ... but the best I can think of is to try adding all possible tags into "Do not indent children of" and "Keep white spaces inside" options as well as other options like "Keep line breaks"... I'm just thinking -- if this will help with HTML ... will it actually allow to do anything with actual PHP code in between?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable formatter for a particular code fragments using `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` markers. Make sure they are enabled in Preferences | Editor | Code Style - Formatter control.

[image]

Comment: Yeah so i'll go into my site templates and add markers everywhere, i have 250 templates to do, it won't make my code ugly too...

Comment: This is for specific case, not application wide